# prove characterstic polynomial of $2\times 2$ matrix is $C_{A}(x)=x^2-(\lambda_{1}+ \lambda_{2})x+\lambda_{1} \lambda_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Let $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$ not necessarily distinct, be the eigenvalues of A. Show that
$$
C_{A}(x)=x^2-(\lambda_{1}+ \lambda_{2})x+\lambda_{1} \lambda_{2}
$$

I'm not too good at proofs but this is what I've thought of. I know that this statement is equivalent to $$C_{A}(x)=x^2-\text{tr}(A)x+\det(A).$$. Therefore, I claim that $tr(A)=\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}$ and $det(A)=\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}$. However, I'm not too sure how to prove these claims. Any alternative or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Do you know that the eigenvalues of a matrix are exactly the roots of its characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @brick. I know but I dont't see how that helps me

Comment: Expand $(x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)$.

Comment: If you have the equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ and $x, y$ are its roots, then $b = -(x+y)/a$ and $c = xy/a$. Vieta's formulas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Using the facts
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)\\
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)
$$
You can show that for any invertible matrix $S$, we have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(SAS^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr}(A)\\
\det(SAS^{-1}) = \det(A)
$$
Now, select an $S$ such that $SAS^{-1}$ is upper-triangular.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by a comment, note that by the definition of an eigenvalue
$$
x^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)x + \det(A) = (x-\lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)
$$